# Images than span entire screen on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autolayout

I am creating an app that is displayed in landscaped mode. What I am running into is I have a graphic that stretches across the screen. How do I account for the iPhone and iPhone 5 with this. I have a UIImageView that is 60px high and needs to stretch all the way across the screen. From what I read there is no naming convention to indicate I am using an iPhone 5 graphic. Do I need to make one graphic at 1136X120(iPhone 5) one at 960X120(iPhone 4s) and one at 480X60(iPhone 4). What I am afraid of is that if I just use the 1136X120 for both the iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s that it would squeeze the 1136 into 960, this how it works or is there something I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any specific naming convention for iPhone 5 images that I'm aware of. Instead, have an @2x image with a different name than the regular images. Then, in your app, check for if the current device is an iphone 5 screen and use the other image if so. I recommend adding a function like this to a class, and then adding that class to your pre-compiled header file (.pch) so that it is accessible across your entire app.

```
BOOL iPhone5Screen()
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return NO;
} else {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
        //
        if(result.height >= 1136){
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: +1 Yeah I was thinking about that earlier, that I could programmatically identify the iPhone 5 then sub in a wider image. It just seems that if I have a lot of images that stretch the entire screen's width that it will become a lot of work. I am hoping that there is someway to do this in IB.